# What happens to $\int_a^b \sin(\sqrt[n]{x})\,dx$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

It seems that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b \sin(\sqrt[n]{x})\,dx=b-a$$ where $a,b$ are in degrees (not radians).

**Example**

When $a=45$, $b=60$ and $n=10^{99}$, my calculator gives $$\int_{45}^{60} \sin(\sqrt[10^{99}]{x})\,dx=14.99...\approx60-45.$$

Wolfram gives [this indefinite integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(x%5E1%2Fn)) but I have no idea how this is obtained.

How should I begin proving this? Is there a similar identity for $\cos(\sqrt[n]{x})$?

Comment: Warning - I haven't worked out the details exactly. Because of the `in degrees', I'd guess that the answer you're getting is $\frac{\sin(\pi/180)}{\pi/180} (b-a),$ where the arguments are in the usual radians. Note that since $\pi/180$ is small, and $\sin x/x \to 1$ as $x \to 0,$ this should thus be around $b-a$ ( $ \sim 0.99995 (b-a)$ to be more precise). The parallel conjecture for cosines then suggests that you'll get an answer $\sim 57 (b-a)$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks for the comment! But I'm afraid I have to disagree with the 'parallel conjecture for cosines' since $$\int_{30}^{60} \cos(\sqrt[10^{99}]{x})\,dx=29.99...\approx60-30$$ not $57(60-30)$.

Comment: Ah. I'll think some more then. Just to see if I'm along the right lines, can you just do the sine integral for $n = 1$ instead of $10^{99}?$ If the answer is not around $9.1,$ then I'm probably totally wrong. (Aside - the answer you've received is of course correct, but disagrees with what you observe. This makes me think that this has to do with your input method and the calculator, which is what I'm trying to test with $n=1$ case.)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 If $n=1$ then $\sin(\sqrt[n]{x})=\sin x$ which is extremely easy to integrate...

Comment: Indeed, but with the calculator in degree mode, I suspect that the operation being performed is $\int \sin( \pi x^{1/n} /180\, \textrm{rad}) \,\mathrm{d} x,$ The $n=1$ case will help check if this is indeed the case, and should at least confirm or debunk the first part of my first comment.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Well $$\int_{30}^{60} \sin x\,dx=20.97...$$

Comment: Oh cool, so that works, since the answer you're getting is $\frac{180}{\pi} \left(\sin \frac{\pi}{3} - \sin \frac{\pi}{6}\right),$ which fits the operations I had in mind. I'll try and see why the cosine is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0<a<b$ then the function $\sin(\sqrt[n]x)$ converges uniformly to $\sin(1)$ for $x\in[a,b]$.
Consequently,
\begin{align}
\int_a^b\sin(\sqrt[n]x)\,\mathrm dx
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int_a^b\sin(1)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=(b-a)\sin(1)
\end{align}
Similarly,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b\cos(\sqrt[n]x)\,\mathrm dx=(b-a)\cos(1)$$

---

Note that the results generalizes for any integrable function $f$ continuous at $1$, that's
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf(\sqrt[n]x)\,\mathrm dx=(b-a)f(1)$$
In particolar this holds also for the functions
\begin{align}
&\sin\left(\frac\pi{180}x\right)&
&\cos\left(\frac\pi{180}x\right)\\
\end{align}